# Deduce the inequality $|z_{1} + z_{2} + z_{3}| \leq |z_{1}| + |z_{2}| + |z_{3}|$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

I am a beginner in math, and I have solved this question in a way I'm not really sure if it is right.

1. Let $w = z_{2} + z_{3}$. Then, by the triangle inequality, $|z_{1} + w| \leq |z_{1}| + |w|$.
2. Also by the triangle inequality, $|w| = |z_{2} + z_{3}| \leq |z_{2}| + |z_{3}|$.
3. Using $(1)$ and $(2)$, we can conclude that $|z_{1} + z_{2} + z_{3}| \leq |z_{1}| + |z_{2} + z_{3}| \leq |z_{1}| + |z_{2}| + |z_{3}|$. Proven.

I would like to know if such solution is right and, if not, which path should I take in solving this question. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: This is a correct proof.